# How do I know which direction the players will be lining up to sing the national anthem?

Tags: football, venues, copa-america

I just bought tickets for the 2016 Copa America Centenario Argentina vs Chile game at the Levi Stadium in Santa Clara California. My question is, how do I know which direction the players will be lining up to sing the national anthem? I don't want to be staring at the back of their heads o want to be facing them, and I need to know which side of the stadium I would have to be sitting at.

Comment: They normally seem to face the tunnel they came out of (assuming it isn't in a corner), where the dugouts are.

Comment: Yea but there are like 6 dugouts 1 on each side and in every corner

Comment: I am referring to the one where the coaching staff and substitutes sit. I don't know that stadium but in europe these are always along one side, usually either side of the tunnel the players emerge from.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to be facing them that bad?

Comment: Ehh I think it's an Argentine patriotic thing to be able to stand tall with you team and at least being able to see their faces haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time players will be facing the **main stand**.

I'm going with the smaller one of the two long sides as the main stand. *But it's a guess!*
Going on the image below you would have to buy tickets in one of the sections going from 131 till 145 (lower tier) or 232-246 (upper tier)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A good way to identify the main stand they will be facing is to look for the VIP seating / Royal Box / Press seating. They will be facing in that direction.

Mind, in some cases, if there are flags being raised or flown, some teams will turn to face in that direction.